# Is there a good Fogbugz client for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, fogbugz

And/or: do I need one?

I've recently started using FogBugz for my hobby projects, and I'm very happy with things so far. Having read more about it, especially the evidence-based scheduling, I'd like to start using it for my PhD as well. (Heh; something tells me my supervisors won't be opening tickets for me, though.)

Last night I stumbled onto [TimePost](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/loadFile.do?objectId=9016), which looks like a tidy app that doesn't do much but could be a real bonus to logging my time in FogBugz effectively. I tried looking around for similar apps but came up a little empty-handed. Are there any other FogBugz clients that you've used and recommend for Mac OS X? Or are you happy with the web interface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The official answer is no, there is not a dedicated Mac client, other than Safari :)

There's a [command line version](http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?W840) that runs on Linux, Windows, and Mac.

There are also plans for an iPhone version although I'm not technically supposed to announce features before they are done or even spec'd so pretend I didn't say that.

Answer (score 6):

I recently spotted this one which looks quite nice for additions:

http://manicwave.com/products/tickets

Comment: I've been using the trial for 30 days, and have now bought the full product! I appraised both this and LadyBugz, and Tickets won the battle!

Answer (score 5):

I'm happy with using the web interface. I've used [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) to create a custom browser for it, and even gotten some help making [a pretty icon](http://www.flickr.com/groups/fluid_icons/discuss/72157605174142635/).

Answer (score 5):

We recently released a new Fogbugz client software for Mac, maybe you are interested to give it a try, http://lithoglyph.com/ladybugz/

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading that there was a client in development, and I believe they're still looking for beta testers. See this URL

http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?fogbugz.4.24403.0

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug here, but you might wanna check out QuickBugz --- it is a lightweight program that integrates into your status menu. http://www.quickbugzapp.com

Answer (score 1):

I have been very happily using the [Tickets](http://manicwave.com/products/tickets) program from Manic Wave for a few weeks now. it provides a very fluid experience. I am using it in a pressure cooker of doing a competition entry in my odd hours around my day job.

Tickets makes it incredibly easy to create lots of small cases and juggle them between different milestones. I particularly like its outline view which helps when doing task breakdowns into sub-tasks.

Being a long way from the Fogbugz servers, in Western Australia, the speed of a searchable local interface is very much appreciated.

The UI has a lot of nice little Macisms such as mouse over a milestone and see the hours summarized.

Support has also been very prompt and comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any other such Mac tool. I've never found the web interface too bad personally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any native tool, but like Matt I am pretty happy with the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

The beta of Safari 4 and SSB feature is a pretty good option...

Answer (score 0):

I found using a Mac browser w/ the screen snapshot and search engine add-on to be very useful. I think what you are saying is that it can be hard to edit your timesheets, but that is part of the web design.

Answer (score 0):

I've just released [Bee](http://neat.io/bee), which is a Mac client for FogBugz.  (It also pulls in your tasks from GitHub and JIRA.)

It offers several benefits over the web interface and is designed to be simple, fast and elegant.  You can check it out at: http://www.neat.io/bee/fogbugz.html